# multiple domains redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

i have a website, example: **mydomain.com**

then i have other domains, for example: **mydomain.org, mydomain.net**,.. set with cpanel addon domains function the on directory /domain/ with an index.php file inside

in this way when a user go on mydomain.net or .org is redirected from the /domain/index.php file on the main website (mydomain.com)

eveything work fine except if a user type **mydomain.net/somefile** or **mydomain.net/somedir/somefile**, in these cases the user get an 404 error message

my question is: there is a way (with htaccess) to remove everything from the url exept the domain (in this way if a user type mydomain.net/somefile or mydomain.net/somedir/somefile
 is redirected normally by the /domain/index.php file)?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^ domain/index.php [L]
```

This intercepts all `404`s for any domain (except mydomain.com) and serves the request from `/domain/index.php`. If you'd like the address bar URL to change as well; say, from `mydomain.net/somefile` to `mydomain.net` use the redirection `[R]` flag as

```
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

---

***/domain/.htaccess*** :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

`%{HTTP_HOST}` condition was dropped because only non `.com` domains are mapped to `/domain`.

Comment: +1 I was typing very similar answer then saw your answer being posted and cancelled mine :)

Comment: Thx Ravi, but there is no a way to add an **.htaccess** in my **/domain** directory, and simply remove **{REQUEST_URI}** and **{QUERY_STRING}**

Comment: @ipel, I'm not sure if `/domain/.htaccess` would take affect since the request URL doesn't include the directory but since the cpanel does the mapping here you might as well test this approach by placing the updated `.htaccess` code there.